# R - contour plot in three variables

Tags: r, plot

I'd like to know if there is a way to produce plots in R function similar to Mathematica's [ContourPlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html) function? Basically, it allows you to plot a 3D surface at values of ***f***, where ***f*** is an implicit function in three variables. The example from Mathematica: ***f(x,y,z) = x^3 + y^2 + z^2***.

```
x <- y <- z <- seq(-2, 2, by=0.2)
grid <- expand.grid(x=x,y=y,z=z)
grid$f <- x^3 + y^2 + z^2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the plot3D package.

The [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plot3D/vignettes/plot3D.pdf) has similar examples to the Mathematica [link you provided](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html).

Install the package, scan the vignette for the relevant function you want and try out that functions examples.  For instance, if you want to look at the contour3D function and the surf3D function:

```
install.packages("plot3D")
require("plot3D")
example(contour3D)
example(surf3D)
```

You may want `slice3D()` or `isosurf3D()`.

You can also try the `misc3d` package.

```
require(misc3d)

x <- y <- z <- seq(-2, 2, by=0.2)

x <- seq(-2,2,len=50)
g <- expand.grid(x = x, y = x, z = x)
v <- array(g$x^3 + g$y^2 + g$z^2, rep(length(x),3))
con <- computeContour3d(v, max(v), level=.2)

drawScene(makeTriangles(con))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I applied the misc3d example directly to my function and the resulting plot is as expected. I've used it to plot the constraint region of the group LASSO.